# pandas kmeans how to work with categorical attributes

Tags: pandas, k-means, categorical-data

I work with Cloudera 5.2 VM and pandas 0.18.0
I want to apply kmeans to my dataframe. But I have str columns.

My dataframe is

```
adClicksPerTime.head(n=5)
Out[50]: 
            timestamp   adCategory  userId  totalAdClicks
0 2016-05-26 15:00:00   automotive     355              1
1 2016-05-26 15:00:00     clothing    1027              1
2 2016-05-26 15:00:00    computers    1821              1
3 2016-05-26 15:00:00    computers    2139              1
4 2016-05-26 15:00:00  electronics     253              1

for col in adClicksPerTime:
     print(col)
     print(type(adClicksPerTime[col][1]))


timestamp
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
adCategory
<class 'str'>
userId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
totalAdClicks
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

When I execute kmeans I get the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'automotive'
```

I tried to convert my string to categorical type and after to assign numeric codes

```
adClicksPerTime.adCategory = pd.Categorical.from_array(adClicksPerTime.adCategory)     

adClicksPerTime.head(n=5)
Out[54]: 
            timestamp   adCategory  userId  totalAdClicks
0 2016-05-26 15:00:00   automotive     355              1
1 2016-05-26 15:00:00     clothing    1027              1
2 2016-05-26 15:00:00    computers    1821              1
3 2016-05-26 15:00:00    computers    2139              1
4 2016-05-26 15:00:00  electronics     253              1

for col in adClicksPerTime:
     print(col)
     print(type(adClicksPerTime[col][1]))


timestamp
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
adCategory
<class 'str'>
userId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
totalAdClicks
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

How can I apply kmeans to this str field?

Comment: k-means is designed for **continuous** variables only. Don't use it on this kind of data!

Answer (score 1):

Get dummies will change the Categories to dummies.

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(adClicksPerTime[adCategory])
del dummies['automotive']
print dummies.columns
```

Then merge this DataFrame with `adClicksPerTime` dataFrame, Finally apply Kmeans.

`adClicksPerTime.info()` will give you  dtypes.